# Is there a need for Smartphone Antivirus?

Tags: anti-virus

Has anyone came across a need for smartphone antivirus software?  If so, what have you tried or read about that sounds good?  I have a Palm Pre with WebOS, but this is more for a topic for a computer club meeting so anything that you found that works good would be helpful.

Comment: For what phone brands specifically? (I've heard good things about F-Secure's stuff — http://www.f-secure.com/en_EMEA/products/mobile/mobile-security/ — but then the guy who said that works for them. :-)

Comment: You might want to also add what phone OS - Symbian S60 3rd, Windows Mobile, etc.

Comment: what the heck, mobile phones are no longer a safe haven from the 'culture of fear'? :)

Comment: I did tell you the OS, WebOS.  WebOS is a smartphone platform, powered by Linux, and developed by Palm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally never tried this software, but I've read about it [Flexilis](https://beta.flexilis.com/) is a new smartphone antivirus.  The website says Flexilis works across a variety of smartphones, so if you have a common smartphone, it should work on yours.

Answer (score 1):

Phone of a daughter of my coworker was recently infected. She was able to cure it with http://products.drweb.com/mobile/win/

I must admit that I work for this company so my opinion can be biased :-)

Comment: I do like the looks of that product, but it doesn't look like it is supporting the WebOS platform.  Thanks for the link though, it might come in useful for other phones.